# In Eclipse, "Show in Local Terminal" suddenly disappeared - Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly the useful function to open Git Bash disappeared.
Has anyone had the same issue?
How to restore it?

Edit: my Windows version is okay but the one on Ubuntu has this problem. and both of them have the same add-ons.

[image: Show in Local Terminal]

Comment: Did you change anything?

Comment: @nitind Not big changes I guess. I installed one or two add-ons from the marketplace. I will check it... thanks. strange thing is that I have two versions. One for Windows and the other one for Ubuntu(Hyper-V VM) and both have the same add-ons. This problem occurs only the one for Ubuntu.